# Android Gps Coordinates

Tags: java, android, xml, gps

I am new to Android apps development, I am trying to get the GPS coordinates but i am not able to figure it out where my code has problem. i am using android studio 1.4 version and the project is built on ICE CREAM Sandwich 4.0.3
Using some articles i tried to get the coordinates but i am always facing problem getting the coordinates.

Here is my code

This is how i am defining permission setting in my manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

these are the controls i have in my content_main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:text="Latitude: "
android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="unknown"
android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView03"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:text="Longitute: "
android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView04"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="unknown"
android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and finally this is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.dell.soslocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     
LocationListener {

private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAction("Action", null).show();
}
});

latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

// Get the location manager
locationManager = (LocationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
// default
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// TODO: Consider calling
// public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int 
requestCode)
// here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
// public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
permissions,
// int[] grantResults)
// to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the 
documentation
// for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
return;
}
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

// Initialize the location fields
if (location != null) {
System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
onLocationChanged(location);
} else {
latituteField.setText("Location not available");
longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
}
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// TODO: Consider calling
// public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int 
requestCode)
// here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
// public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
permissions,
// int[] grantResults)
// to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the 
documentation
// for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
return;
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// TODO: Consider calling
// public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int 
requestCode)
// here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
// public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
permissions,
// int[] grantResults)
// to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the 
documentation
// for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
return;
}
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

There is no error i got when i ran the app in android emulator Nexus 4 Api 23 but its not displaying any coordinates, since the provider is always null. And when i install in my device its not starting and giving the error "unfortunately the app has stopped"

Can somebody tell me whats wrong in my code.

Thanks,

Comment: Please can you normally indent your code? Do not drop the whole bunch of code here. Only the relevant parts. Remove the xml files as why did you post them? Only the location listener would do and how you instantiate it. Remove the 'run code snippet' and other button from your post.

Comment: @greenapps, sorry for droping all the code here but i was thinking if i give the complete code then someone could able to suggest me where i am wrong. But i have edited my code the way you said.

Comment: Thanks. But still your code is not indented. So unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is an easy way to get the coordinates, 
//activity-main.xml  

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_longitude"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

  //MainActivity.java 

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Criteria;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    LocationManager locationManager ;
    String provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting LocationManager object
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating an empty criteria object
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

    // Get the location from the given provider
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);

    if(location!=null)
    onLocationChanged(location);
    else
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

    // Setting Current Longitude
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    // Setting Current Latitude
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Sai, I tried the way you mentioned here but my app always crashing without even starting. I dont know whats wrong with my coding. i did everything to make it run but no luck. If you can help me i can post my complete sample app. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sai, Your code is correct and even the code which i have posted is working correctly. The problem i faced with the new version of Android SDK 23. Since i am new to Android development and i don't know how to define the permission in code. The new version requires the permissions to be defined in the java class file whenever we try to access something like gps etc.. even if you define in manifest.xml file. So i downgraded my sdk to 22 and its working fine now. If in future someone who have good knowledge of sdk 23 please post the answer here which supports sdk version 23.